# Visual Studio: Can't View Files in a Directory in Project

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC3 project. I copied the `Image` directory in `Content` from the file system. It works just fine but I can't open the image directory in Visual Studio. What can I do to resolve this?

[image: Solution Explorer]

Comment: Right click -- Add Existing Item -- choose images?  Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: oh yes, please add an answer so I can accept. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you need to add the images to your project/solution, versus just placing the images in the folder.

To do so, right click on the Images folder in VS Solution Explorer, then select Add Existing Item, and then choose the images to include in the project/solution add click Add.